# Why is this segfaulting? strtok?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

So i am curious as to why the following segment of code keeps segfaulting. It looks correct to me.

```
int * addCoins(char *val){
    const char *deli = ",";
    char *ptr =NULL;

    char *denomination = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr);
    char *count = strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptr);
    int deno = atoi(denomination);
    int cnt = atoi(count);
    int *k;
    k = malloc(sizeof(*k)*2);
    k[0] = deno;
    k[1] =cnt;

    return k;
}
```

the call to the function addCoins in main. I do not think the fault lies in here but i honestly am at a bit of loss with this problem.

```
char* fileNameCoin = argv[2];
FILE *fileCoin;
fileCoin = fopen(fileNameCoin, "r+");
char bufCoin[256];
int i = 0;
//vmNode->next = NULL;
int *j;
while (fgets(bufCoin, sizeof bufCoin, fileCoin) != NULL) {
    j = addCoins(bufCoin);
    int deno = j[0];
    switch(deno){
        case 5:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 10:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 20:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 50:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 100:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 200:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 500:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        case 1000:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    i++;
}
```

The following is how the file is defined

```
1000,3
500,4
200,20
100,30
50,5
20,3
10,40
5,20
```

where the first number is the denomination in cents, and the 2nd column is the number of said denomination.

These are the typedefs:

```
/* The different denominations of coins available */
enum denomination
{
    FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR,
    TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
};

/* Each coin in the coins array will have a denomination (20 cents,
 * 50 cents, etc) and a count - how many of that coin do we have on hand
 */
struct coin
{
    enum denomination denom;
    unsigned count;
};
```

Comment: where exactly the segfault happens?

Comment: It happens in the addCoins function, at the strtok_r line.

Comment: argv[1] contains another filename.

Comment: Blank line is present at the end of the file?

Comment: You're leaking memory like a sieve; you should include `free(j);` at the end of the loop.  You could collapse your `switch` so that `case 5: case 10: case 20: case 50: case 100: case 200: case 500: case 100: Coins[i].denom = j[0]; Coins[i].count = j[1]; break;`.  I'm not sure that simply ignoring erroneous data is a good idea; report an error too.  And do check the return value from `strtok_r()` — but well done for using that and not `strtok()`.  And where's the check that the file was opened successfully?

Comment: Nope. So it looks like doesnt it. fml.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i should. Though doesnt help with my segfault. :/

Comment: Incidentally, if the value from the file is invalid, you leave an entry in the `Coins` array with uninitialized values because you increment `i` regardless of whether you assign or not.  With the collapsed switch I showed in a previous comment, you can include the `i++` in that one case, leaving the erroneous data case without an increment for `i`.

Comment: You might like to compile with symbols and use a debugger.

Comment: "*It happens in the addCoins function, at the strtok_r line.*" there are two lines! *sigh*

Comment: Does it crash already after reading the first line of the file ? If not, at which line of the file does it crash ? Also try to put a `printf("%s\n", val)` just before the call to `strtok_r`.

Comment: You should consider adding debugging print statements, such as 'printf("%s", bufCoin);` (where `bufCoin` holds a newline, one assumes).  Also, you should check that `malloc()` succeeds.

Comment: Check if `fileCoin` is different from `NULL` after `fopen`. If yes that means the file couldn't been opened and you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does your file contains an empty new line at the end? What would happen with `addCoin` if `fgets` returns a string with a single `\n` char?

Comment: um the file crashes immediately after the first strtok_r call within the addCoins function. It will print out val when printf("%s",val); is used prior to the first strtok_r but nothing afterwards. @JonathanLeffler how can i check to see that strtok_r return of strtok_r without it affecting the location of the pointer?

Comment: @DidierTrosset there is not a \n case at the end of the file i have checked several time.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i have used a printf statement just before the call to strtok thats how i know its where it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, you should be using `structs` better via `typedef`.  Example (Invoke with `exename in.txt`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* The different denominations of coins available */
enum denomination {
    FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR,
    TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
};

typedef struct {
    enum denomination denom;
    unsigned int count;
} coin;

coin * addCoins(char *val) {
    coin *k = malloc(sizeof(coin));
    if( sscanf( val, "%d,%d", &(k->denom), &(k->count)) != 2 ) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Two int values not found on line '%s' in input.\n", val);
      free(k);
      k=NULL;
    }
    return k;
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    coin Coins[100]={0};
    char* fileNameCoin = argv[1];
    FILE *fileCoin = fopen(fileNameCoin, "r+");
    char bufCoin[256];
    int i = 0;
    coin *j;
    if( fileCoin ) {
      while(fgets(bufCoin, sizeof bufCoin, fileCoin) != NULL) {
        j = addCoins(bufCoin);                                                                                       
        if( j ) { // only add if 2 int values found on input line
          Coins[i] = *j;
          free(j);
          printf("c: %d, %d\n", Coins[i].denom, Coins[i].count);
          i++;
        } 
      }
      fclose(fileCoin);
    }
    else {
      fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file %s for input.\n",fileNameCoin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a more radical reimplementation of your code which is actually pretty good.  Here's a set of clean-ups applied to your original code; it suggests that whatever problem there was in the program was not in the code shown.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum denomination
{
    FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR,
    TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
};

struct coin
{
    enum denomination denom;
    unsigned count;
};

static struct coin Coins[10];

static
int *addCoins(char *val)
{
    const char *deli = ",";
    char *ptr = NULL;

    char *denomination = strtok_r(val, deli, &ptr);
    char *count = strtok_r(NULL, deli, &ptr);
    printf("D = %s, C = %s", denomination, count);
    int deno = atoi(denomination);
    int cnt = atoi(count);
    printf("D = %d, C = %d\n", deno, cnt);
    int *k = malloc(sizeof(*k) * 2);
    if (k == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    k[0] = deno;
    k[1] = cnt;

    return k;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    char *fileNameCoin = argv[1];
    FILE *fileCoin = fopen(fileNameCoin, "r+");
    if (fileCoin == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    char bufCoin[256];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(bufCoin, sizeof bufCoin, fileCoin) != NULL)
    {
        int *j = addCoins(bufCoin);
        int deno = j[0];
        switch (deno)
        {
        case 5:
        case 10:
        case 20:
        case 50:
        case 100:
        case 200:
        case 500:
        case 1000:
            Coins[i].denom = j[0];
            Coins[i].count = j[1];
            printf("(%d,%d)\n", Coins[i].denom, Coins[i].count);
            i++;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized coin denomination (%d,%d)\n", j[0], j[1]);
            break;
        }
        free(j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -g -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror coins.c -o coins
```

The `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` was necessary to get `strtok_r()` declared.

Example run:

```
D = 1000, C = 3
D = 1000, C = 3
(1000,3)
D = 500, C = 4
D = 500, C = 4
(500,4)
D = 200, C = 20
D = 200, C = 20
(200,20)
D = 100, C = 30
D = 100, C = 30
(100,30)
D = 50, C = 5
D = 50, C = 5
(50,5)
D = 20, C = 3
D = 20, C = 3
(20,3)
D = 10, C = 40
D = 10, C = 40
(10,40)
D = 5, C = 20
D = 5, C = 20
(5,20)
```

Comment: Yeah it turned out i was looking jn the wrong spot for the bug. It was located further down where i had a dodgy implimentation of a container for a list.

Comment: Debuggers and print statements are both effective for finding the place where the crash occurs.  When you have the right place for the crash, you can start looking for the cause.  Reproducibility is first, then localizing, then finding the cause, then resolving the problem, then retesting.

Comment: Yeah thats how i normally approach this. The problem was the crash was occuring in the addcoin function, but it was a result of something else. As for a debugger ill have to get more familiar gdb. As i have yet to find a reasonable debugger with a nice ui for mint. Any suggestions?

Comment: I use GDB; I doubt if that qualifies as 'a nice UI'.  I don't use an IDE; I haven't found one that doesn't get in the way more than it helps.